# Write the array notation as pointer notation

Tags: c

The question is `&str[2]`, if I write `str+2` then it would give the address and its logical but where did I used pointer notation in it?

Should I prefer writing `&(*(str+2))`?

Comment: Don't use that last notation; it's just unreadable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either

```
&str[2]
```

or

```
(str + 2)
```

Both of these are equivalent.

Comment: brackets in the 2nd one are necessary?

Comment: @fahad Parentheses aren't required. I just added those for readability.

Answer (score 4):

This is pointer arithmetic. So when you mention an array `str` or `&str` you refer to the base address of the array (in `printf` for example) i.e. the address of the first element in the array `str[0]`.

From here on, every single increment fetches you the next element in the array. So `str[1]` and `(str + 1)` should give you the same result.

Also, if you have num[] = {24, 3}

then `num[0]` == `*(num + 0)` == `*(0 + num)` == `0[num]`

Comment: There are two mistakes in your answer. First, `&(str + 1)` shouldn’t work (didn’t actually check but pretty certain) because you can’t use the address-of operator on a pointer. Secondly, `&num[0] == num[0]` is wrong, and so is the rest of your equation.

Comment: @konrad thanks! Just wrote a small snippet to check it out. You were correct! Edited my post.

Comment: @Konrad: `&(str+1)` is invalid because you can't take the address of a temporary variable, not because you can't take the address of a pointer...!

Comment: @movieyoda: It's worth clarifying that in the case of a stack array, `&str` and `str` are *not* the same thing.  In particular, `(str+1)` and `(&str+1)` will not point at the same address (unless the array happens to be of length 1).

Comment: @Oli: you’re right of course. But a question about stack arrays (don’t know C …): why do they behave differently? Doesn’t a stack array name decay to a pointer same as a normal array? Or is taking the address of a stack array somehow different from pointer decay?

Comment: @Konrad: A stack-based array (e.g. `int x[5];`) is of array type (`int [5]`).  Therefore `&x` is of type `int (*) 5`.  So `&x+1` will add `sizeof(int [5])` to the address of `x`; there is no array-to-pointer decay here.  This is not true of heap-based arrays (e.g. `int *x = malloc(...);`, because they are necessarily declared as pointers.